# How to pass special parameter into os.system in Python3?

Tags: python

I am passing parameter into os.system in Python3 like this:

```
os.system("scrapy crawl %s -a arg='%s'" % ("googlebook",scrapy_url))
```

the scrapy url contains special charactor:

```
'?q=19434&maxResults=40&startIndex=200'
```

In the Spider only recieve:

```
?q=19434
```

How to pass special words into spider?

Comment: Escape them with backslashes

Comment: Or use `subprocess` module with proper command line arguments passing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shlex` module knows how to escape strings you want to pass to the shell.

However, the shell isn't doing anyting useful here, so it's better to simply avoid it.

```
from subprocess import run
run(["scrapy", "crawl", "googlebook", "-a", "arg=" + scrapy_url],
    # This will raise an exception if scrapy fails
    # which is _probably_ a good idea in most scenarios
    check=True)
```

Of course, given that `scrapy` is a Python library, perhaps the best solution is to simply `import scrapy` and take it from there.